# Integrating ogre3d with hololens

Tags: c++, directx11, ogre, hololens

I would like to integrate ogre3d with directx and c++ using hololens.

is it that possible to do so ?

what are the steps to convert the rendering engine, what's rendered to the frame buffer to the hololens buffer?

Comment: Cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471489/integrating-ogre3d-with-hololens